# Keycloak uma-grant type tickets for service accounts do not seem to work with policies

Tags: permissions, authorization, keycloak, authz

I am trying to use the Keycloak AuthzClient to register resources and related permissions in a resource server.

I have a resource server "resourceserver" with authz service enabled.

Using the AuthzClient, initialized with the json file containing the resource server's client id and secret, I'm able to obtain a pat.

```
    ...
    authzClient.obtainAccessToken().getToken();
    ResourceRepresentation resource = new ResourceRepresentation();
    resource.setName("myresource");
    resource.setUris(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList("urn:resourceserver:resourcetype1:myresource")));
    resource.setOwnerManagedAccess(true);
    resource.setType("urn:resourceserver:resourcetype1");
    resource.addScope("read", "write");
    resource = authzClient.protection(pat).resource().create(resource);


    UmaPermissionRepresentation permissionRepresentation = new UmaPermissionRepresentation();
    permissionRepresentation.setName("myresourcepermissions");
    permissionRepresentation.setDescription("foo");
    permissionRepresentation.addRole("somerole");
    UmaPermissionRepresentation result = authzClient.protection(pat).policy(resource.getId()).create(permissionRepresentation)
```

After executing this code, I can see, in the keycloak admin UI, that the resource has been created, and the scopes, however the policy/permission don't seem to show up.

I believe it is probably intended, as this keycloak admin UI only shows policies of types client, role, js, etc., but not "uma" which is what UmaPermissionRepresentation creates.

I can however see that policy exists in Keycloak by querying `authz/protection/uma-policy` with my pat.

So there is something there.  Now testing it.  I created a regular user and assigned it the realm role `somerole`.  Using this user and some arbitrary public client, I'm able to get an RPT.

First getting an access token using the password grant:

`grant_type=password&username=joe&password=password&client_id=somepublicclient`

Then exchanging that for an RPT:

`grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket&audience=resourceserver`

The RPT comes back and if I view its contents, I can see the authorization block giving me access to the myresource resource.

However, when I try a similar flow with a service account (to which I also granted the `somerole` role)using the client credentials flow to obtain the initial access token:

`grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=serviceaccount1&client_secret=77c1ffa8-0ea8-420c-ad45-e1a69a03838d`

I am able to obtain an RPT, but that RPT does not contain myresource in the authorization/permission block, only the Default resource.

I have been trying to understand why that is.  I have also tried using the `.addClient("serviceaccount1")`  or even `.addUser("service-account-serviceaccount1")` in the UmaPermissionRepresentation, but still, the policy doesn't seem to kick in and my service account does not have access to the resource.

This is using Keycloak 4.8.0.Final.

Note: using the keycloak admin client, I am able to create policies/permissions that actually make this work; but in my environment this would causes other problems because of the roles I would need to assign to the admin client (like viewing all clients to retrieve an id etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with KeyCloak 11.0.2.
Shared resources do not end up in the permission tickets of service accounts. Service accounts are [explicitly excluded](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/authorization/AuthorizationTokenService.java#L590) in the authorization token service.
Since sharing resources with service accounts is possible, this seems inconsistent.

However, you can work around this by explicitly setting the `azp` claim to something other than your `client_id` via a protocol mapper on your client.

[image: protocol mapper on your client].